# Access and update output variables dynamically in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

- Edited for new error *

I have created a handful of UI elements using a dynamic dataset. When a button is selected, I would like to update those elements dynamically from the server using a variable. I'm not sure how to access the output in order to do that as I can't use a variable using the '$' selector (from my understanding). I tried using output[[var]], but I get an error. Any ideas how I can achieve this? Example application below. I used the reactiveVal solution below, but getting a new error when trying to use an id to identify the specific reactiveVal. Not sure what I'm doing wrong now.

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    actionButton("button", "Test"),
    uiOutput("test")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    section_ids <- paste0("test_", 1:9)
    
    answered_questions_reactive <- lapply(section_ids, function(i) {
        id <- paste0(i, "_summary_answered")
        print(id)
        reactiveVal(id)
    })
    
    output$test <- renderUI({

        lapply(section_ids, function(i) {
            test_id <- paste0(i, "_summary_answered")
            print(test_id)
            div(
                id = test_id,
                answered_questions_reactive[[test_id]]()
            )
        })

    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reactive values:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  actionButton("button", "Test"),
  uiOutput("test")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Contents <- lapply(1:5, function(i) reactiveVal(h1(i)))

  output$test <- renderUI({
    
    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      div(
        id = paste("test-", i), 
        Contents[[i]]()
      )
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    print("Updating Summary Tab")
    for(i in 1:5) {
      Contents[[i]](h1(i + 10))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ok, this works in the application you added here - Thank you! When I try to apply this logic to my larger app, I'm getting an error "Warning: Error in dots_list: attempt to apply non-function" when trying to create the div. Any clue what that could be?

Comment: Edited code above to highlight issue.